# Format string that already has format specifier %@

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-formatting

I have a string which already contains a formatter `%@`.

```
NSString *str = @"This is an %@";
```

I need to parse that string and to replace `%@` with 'example'. If I use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
```

I get the following output:

> This is an %@

I want output like:

> This is an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommand to use the formatted string as "format"

```
NSString *str = @"This is an %@";
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:str, @"example"];
```

is working with every type. A better solution than replacing, because you can use unspecified replacings

is very usefull if you use localized.strings with x values you want to add ;)

Comment: The problem here is that this is very fragile. If the format string does not match the argument type you get a crash. Even more dangerous is the case where you have no absolute control over the format string, for example when loaded from the web or managed by a Localizable.strings file. Then an attacker might be able to inject a format string that could be used to take over control in the app. Non-literal format strings a very dangerous and there's even a compiler warning for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str = @"This is an %@";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:@"example"];
```